# What is the use of Order attribute in this Anchor tag?

Tags: html, xhtml

I was wondering that is the purpose of order="4" attribute in this anchor tag?

Can anybody tell me?

```
<a encodeurl="1" order="4" class="menu_footer_contact" href="/demo/help/contact">Contact</a>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (along with `encodeurl`) has [no meaning in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1). It is a non-standard expando attribute, presumably existing to be read by JS in the page and should be [a `data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Comment: means? should use when we want to do some js?

Comment: No. It means you should use it when you are using some particular JS that is in that page and is looking for the non-standard attribute. (Actually, you shouldn't use it, you should rewrite the JS to use a `data-` attribute).